# std::remove_if and erase not removing elements from std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, lambda

I am practicing leetcode easy problem.  I want to remove_if from an vector using lambda (for the first time, It is great).  I get a negative pointer for new_end.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>   // std::greater

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> a = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
    int target = 9;

    auto new_end = std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [&a, target](const int x)
    {
        return std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), x) > target;  
    });
    a.erase(new_end, a.end());
    return 0;
}
```

There is no error but new_end is a negative pointer value.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with "negative pointer value" ? Do you print it somewhere, or how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: There is no such thing as negative pointer

Comment: Does `new_end` equal `end`?  It looks like it should.

Comment: `iterator::end` is not pointing to useful data. It's solely used to determine the end of a collection.

Comment: The value of `new_end` looks reasonable. One thing I'm concerned about is the use of `count(a.begin(), a.end(), x)` within the predicate of `remove_if`. Once an element has been `remove`d, the next call to the predicate will access the removed value by going past  `new_end`. Elements that have been removed have an _unspecified_ value.

Comment: You may want the lambda to be `[target](int x) { return x > target; }`. Your current predicate is bad because after it returns true for any one element it will inspect unspecified values at the end of the vector for all subsequent iterations. And it probably doesn't do what you want anyway because `std::count` counts the number of occurrences of an element in a range.

Comment: I was wrong about the pointer, it was a negative value!

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove_if(begin, end, pred)` returns an *iterator* pointing at the first element to erase or `end` if there is no element matching `pred`. The later is true in your case:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(),
    [&a, target](const int x) { return std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), x) > target; }
);
```

`new_end` equals `a.end()`. This value is printed as garbage by your debugger. But [it happens to just works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e07ead1e93a19af3) by chance in your case.

As pointed out by multiple commentators, once your predicate has returned `true` once, the range [`a.begin()`, `a.end`) is modified and the last element has an unspecified value<sup>1</sup>.

This makes `std::count(a.begin(), a.end(), x)` return unspecified values.

---

A suggested fix is to make a copy of `a` before `remove_if` starts to move things around. This is done by capturing it by value:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(),
    [b=a, target](const int x) { return std::count(b.begin(), b.end(), x) > target; }
);
```

Initializing the copy to a new name `b` simply emphasizes that it is a copy.

---

<sup>1)</sup> From [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

> Iterators pointing to an element between the new logical end and the physical end of the range are still dereferenceable, but the elements themselves have unspecified values (as per MoveAssignable post-condition).

Comment: I don't think the code works. `std::remove_if` modifies the range while the lambda is still counting from it, reading unspecified elements.

Comment: @YSC If the predicate returns true, then the last element has an unspecified value the next time the predicate is called.

Answer (score -1):

I assume to want to remove numbers greater than 9 from vector, Here is the code

```
    vector<int> a = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
    int target = 9;

    auto new_end = std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](const int x)
    {
        return x > 9;

    });
    a.erase(new_end, a.end());
    return 0;
```

The lambda argument 'x' will be provided by `remove_if`, you don't need to add anything in  the capture list

Comment: How did you come to this assumption? And replacing value of variable `target` by hardcoded value is not a good idea.

Comment: @Slava  No assumption here if you know how lambda works then you will understand how it works you create a separate function, you just pass that function

Comment: @DakshGupta *"I assume to want to remove numbers greater than 9"* is definitely an assumption...

Comment: My guess is this is what the OP wants, but dumping a solution without explaining what's wrong with the original code is not very useful. *you don't need to add anything in the capture list* is not necessarily true, if the `9` may vary in the OP's actual use case then that variable needs to be captured